# How to send axios post request with date object in request body?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

My api include name and date data 
Type of name is string .Type of date is string 
Also, In this project includes latest version of Vue.js

```
postTodo(){
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'my-api',
        headers : {
          token: this.token
        },
        data: {
          name : "Hello",
          // it's not working => JSON.stringify(new Date())
          date : JSON.stringify(new Date())
        }
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
      .then( response =>
      console.log(response))
      
    }
```

This is a button for check post request

```
<button @click="postTodo">Send To-Do</button>
```

So, i want to convert from date object to string. How to fix this problem ?

Comment: You don't need to manually stringify the date, just set `date: new Date()` and when Axios converts the request body to JSON, it will be converted to an ISO 8601 string

Comment: I tried before. It doesn't work.

Comment: How is it exactly it doesn't work? Does the API fail? Is the `date`-property null, missing or in the wrong format? What is the problem?

Comment: Wrong format. Because when i declared, it gives this format: Tue Mar 02 2021 03:38:42 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00). I want to take this format : ISO 8601. Also i use ready for use javascript date function => toUTCString. But i didnt convert UTC to ISO. Because javascript allow to use one date function.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. Like this:

```
let dates= new Date()
let month = dates.getUTCMonth() + 1
let day = dates.getUTCDate()
let year = dates.getUTCFullYear()
let currentDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) to create the date and format it

Somethink like

```
dayjs().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Read the Documentation in order to format the date as needed from your API